# How to find exact string in database Field without like

Tags: php, mysql

```
id      hosp_id    provider_settings                               
1       50411      {"e-invoice":"0"}                                    
2       129        {"e-invoice":"0","Document GroupId":"**test**"}           
3       50411      {"e-invoice":"0","Document GroupId":"**testtt**"}        
4       50360      {"e-invoice":"0","Document GroupId":"**yryyyy**"}
```

This is my table structure.

I want to search perfectly match "**test**" string/text in "**provider_settings**" field and record fetch according to **test** string.

But If we search  **test** string/text then no other record should be fetched like **testtt** string/text data.

Please help.

Comment: where is your code sniplet?

Comment: Explode the data inside your db, one column for e-invoice, one for document group-id. Then use = to match test, example: select * from mytable where newColumn = 'test'

Comment: If I update my existing json with adding one more column then? this field "provider_settings" create dynamically.

Comment: Can you give more examples of records you want to fetch, and records you don't want to fetch?

Comment: This is the problem you run into when serialising data inside a single column - you forgo the ability to search and sort on individual subfields. Split them out into a key-value table, or a table containing columns for each property. You can then use SQL on them as normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for "test" and it is a part of json or some other string placed in your db there is other way to find it without LIKE.

Also, if you don't have any special structure of this string, there is not way to get only test (not testtt or similar)

But, if your structure looks always like  ->  ****** value ******
Then just look for it with those * which nicely starts and ends what you are looking for.

i.e

select * from table_name where provider_settings LIKE '%**test**%'

Comment: You could use the quotes as delimiters too.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the exact same string i.e case sensitive matches use BINARY

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE BINARY column_name = 'test'
```

replace table_name and column_name to match your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM v2_statement_provider_api_rel
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('test', REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( provider_settings,  '}',  ',' ) ,  ':',  ',' ) ,  '{',  ',' ) ,  '"',  ',' ) ) >0
```

Comment: This is write answer for my question.

Comment: Abid: you can self-accept your answer in a couple of days, I think.